# route fix messages from one session to another

Tags: quickfixj

I want to route fix messages from one session to another session with quickfixj.

Method1:create multiple sessions in same config file

I know we can do it by creating sessionID in the application manually and send using Session.sendToTarget(message, sessionID); to create sessionID. But I need to pass senderCompID, targetCompID and qualifier manually which I have already provided them in the config file. seems I can't use the config file settings outside of quickfixClientApplication.

Method2: create one session in one config file.

With this approach we create two quickfixjClientApplication and we have flexibility to route message from one application to another.

So, here my question is, in Method1 can we route messages from one session to another session in any other way? or creating multiple sessions in same config file is intended/suggested for routing messages from one session to another. If method1 is not possible, is Method2 is fine? or is there any other approach to do that?

Comment: If you want to route messages programmatically then they need to be in the same Java process since the sessions are stored in a static map.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophJohn,  I understood that. But with method1 is it possible to get sessionIDs from config file? Or to route fix messages from one session to another. Is there any standard approach to prefer?

Comment: If you want to access the config file you need to use SessionSettings class.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophJohn, To route fix messages from one session to another session. Is there any standard approach to prefer?

Comment: Hey @ChristophJohn, let me know If method2 is preferable or does it have performance issues?

Comment: I don't know anything about your application, how it is structured etc. The simplest adaption that you can do performance-wise is to choose either a `(Threaded)SocketInitiator` or `(Threaded)SocketAcceptor`. The `Threaded` ones utilize a thread per session, whereas the default ones use one thread for all sessions. But of course it largely depends on your workload, number of messages, number of sessions etc whether you will notice any difference.